Toggle visibillity of a list in Svelte
I am trying to do the most basic thing in Svelte but I keep failing. I want the button element to trigger the visibillity of the ul-element with classname "this-one". I am stuck in the "vanilla js"-approach and can not wrap my head around how to achieve this the svelte-way. Any pointers?
<ul>
    {#each item.children as child (child.id)}
        <li>
            <div>
                <a href={child.route.path}
                   on:click={() => dispatch('click')}>
                    <span>{child.name}</span>
                </a>
                {#if child.children?.length > 0}
                    <button>
                        <i class="chevron-down"></i>
                    </button>
                {/if}
            </div>
            {#if child.children?.length > 0}
                <ul class="this-one">
                    {#each child.children as grandChild}
                        <li>
                            <a href={grandChild.route.path}
                               on:click={() => dispatch('click')}>
                                {grandChild.name}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    {/each}
                </ul>
            {/if}
        </li>
    {/each}
</ul>


You would have to store the visibility information either on the item object itself or an external object, e.g. a set, map or in an array by index. (You might not want to have it on the item for various data organization reasons.)
E.g. using a Set1:
let expanded = new Set();
function toggle(id) {
    if (expanded.has(id)) {
        expanded.delete(id);
    } else {
        expanded.add(id);
    }
    // trigger reactivity, since object is mutated internally using methods
    expanded = expanded;
}

<button on:click={() => toggle(child.id)}>
    <i class="chevron-down"></i>
</button>

...
{#if child.children?.length > 0 && expanded.has(child.id)}
    <ul class="this-one">
        ...

REPL
If the state is directly on the item, it is the most straightforward:
<button on:click={() => child.expanded = !child.expanded}>
    <i class="chevron-down"></i>
</button>

...

{#if child.children?.length > 0 && child.expanded}
    <ul class="this-one">
        ...

REPL

1 In Svelte 5 you can use the SvelteSet from 'svelte/reactivity', which updates without any dummy assignment. (Such assignments generally do not do anything in Svelte 5.) 
